# Plus.PeopleApi não consegue conectar

Tags: android, google-api

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que irá criar, ler e atualizar alguns documentos no `Drive`.

No `NavigationView`, gostaria de identificar a conta do Usuário. 
Da mesma forma que é feito no app do `Google Play` ou o `Play Music`.

Para isto, adicionei / habilitei a api do Google+ e tentei coletar as informações da seguinte forma:

```
mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this, this).addApi(Drive.API).addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE).addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME)).addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME)).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    connectPeople();
}

private void connectPeople(){
    final PendingResult<People.LoadPeopleResult> people = Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mClient, null);
    people.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull People.LoadPeopleResult peopleData) {
            if (peopleData.getStatus().getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
                PersonBuffer personBuffer = peopleData.getPersonBuffer();
                try {
                    int count = personBuffer.getCount();
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        Log.d("PEOPLE" , "Display name: " + personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName());
                    }
                } finally {
                    personBuffer.release();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ERROR RRRR", peopleData.getStatus().toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No connect: "+peopleData.getStatus().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, connectionResult.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Permissões:**

```
android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
 android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" 
 android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" 
 android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"
 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
 android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"
 android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" 
 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
```

Adicionei as Api’s e criei a chave.

Adicionei o arquivo `google-services.json`

E adicionei  a string `google_app_id`

Toda vez que faço a solicitação ocorre o seguinte erro:

> E/ERROR RRRR: Status{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null}

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Pelo que eu li [na Internet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15410461/1796236), parece que essa API só funciona num APK devidamente assinado e com uma chave que bate com a registrada no seu console de desenvolvedor do Google. Já olhou isso?

Comment: acho que só falta a parte: **num APK devidamente assinado** tentei apenas em debug. Vou testar e informo ! Valeu!